# cairo-dock icons degrade to question marks over time

Tags: 11.10, compiz, gnome, window-manager, cairo-dock

In an up to date 11.10 the Cairo-Dock icons gradually become blue ? circle icons after a few hours or days after restart.  The launchers still work when clicked, but they become harder to identify as more and more of them "forget" their original icon.  Any workarounds to periodically refresh the dock or fixes?
[image: buggy Cairo Dock at bottom]

[image: cropped to dock only]

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I get this happening about once a day in Cairo ... seems when I close Chromium, but not always. Annoying.

Comment: @Mike Nope,never got resolved. Tried many experiments,including the suggestion of switching themes. Nowadays I use (lighter?) Docky under 14.04 w/Gnome.....until it crashes and disappears altogether, and doesn't seem to take new shortcuts via dragNdrop. Comparing with Windows: RocketDock, which just WORKS.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Cairo Dock>Configure, then click on the "Appearance" tab, then try selecting a different theme for icons. If the question marks go away, then it must be a problem with the theme you were using. If that doesn't solve the problem, then you could try choose the correct icon manually for each icon that isn't working. However, to me, it seems strange that you say they fade, or something.... Anyway, hopefully it'll work.

Comment: It's not that some icons are always wrong; it's that one by one they degrade into the same indiscernible blue question mark over time. Besides I'm only using the built-in system themes.